# How does one 'group' 2 ids on one row to filter data on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably a newbie question, but most of my SQL Server experience is basic reporting, with all of my formatting and grouping being made somewhat manually in Excel. Now I am tackling a homework problem that I must solve everything within SQL...

**I have a database with 2 tables:**

1. `Employees(id, job title, partnerID)`
2. `Bugs_Fixed(employeeID, bugs2010, bugs2011, bugs2012)`

Each employee has one partner, who is on the same table (Like if an employee with ID 34 had partner ID 201, then ID 201 would have partnerID 34)

I need to essentially group those 2 together and calculate the combined total number of bugs they fixed (each year combined) without repeating the data for the inverse partner/employee relationship.

For example:

```
| Team    | AMT |       
| 34, 20  | 717 |     
| 76, 16  | 576 |     
| 102, 3  | 901 |
```

I've gotten the query to select based on id, then sum the # of bugs, but that is for each individual employee and it needs to be represented as a group.

```
SELECT employeeID, partnerID, SUM (bugs2010 + bugs2011 + bugs2012) as 'AMT' 
FROM Bugs_Fixed
JOIN Employees on Employees.id = Bugs_Fixed.employeeID
GROUP BY employeeID, partnerID
```

It calculates the yearly bugfixes correctly, but obviously doesn't partner up the 2 ids and their combined total.

Edit: Clarified SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    ARRAY[e1.id, e2.id] AS team, 
    SUM(b.bugs2010) + SUM(b.bugs2011) + SUM(b.bugs2012) AS amt
FROM employees e1
INNER JOIN employees e2 ON e2.partnerID = e1.id AND e1.id < e2.id
INNER JOIN bugs_fixed b ON b.employeeId IN (e1.id, e2.id)
GROUP BY e1.id, e2.id
```

Comment: This should be real Standard SQL, I expect it to work on all RDBMS. I took the array and not string representation, not sure what you wanted to use (but you need no parsing with an array to get to the single items). The clue of this approach is also to get some kind of ordering into the pairs of employees.

Comment: I was having trouble getting the array to work, so I ended up just parsing, but yeah that worked for my needs.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the solution, it seems makes sense until the last parts of the 1st inner join statement.

I've only ever used AND after a WHERE statement, never a JOIN; how is that working?
You're creating the 2nd reference of employees and joining it to the id of the first one, but then what is happening with the e1.id < e2.id?

Comment: The ```AND``` after a ```JOIN ON``` works quite the same way as in a ```WHERE```. For an ```INNER JOIN```, think of a cross product of the tables and apply the condition to it as if it was a where-clause. Thus it is not only checking the "team-relation" but also only picking those teams, where the first member is "smaller" than the second and not their symmetric counterparts.

Comment: I appreciate the info. There must be a fundamental concept of SQL I've forgotten at some point, because its still not quite clicking on why we need the first member to be smaller than the second; Is it because otherwise some of them will display in reverse-order if you don't include that? Like the partner id would show up in the first spot sometimes? Sorry for the pestering, if you have any links that explain this concept better, I'm all eyes.

Comment: It is your requirement, that partners ```(a, b)``` will show up if and only if ```(b, a)``` does not show up. Thus we somehow need to make a distinction between these pairs and make sure that we select only one of them. Since the ```id``` of the employees must be different, this is a good point to enforce the condition. If you have further problems with the ```INNER JOIN``` because it is not just a ```JOIN``` on a ```FOREIGN KEY```, you can also rewrite this and move the additional condition ```e1.id < e2.id``` to the where-clause.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adress this by generating a concatenated key made of the `partnerID` and the `employeeID`. The trick is to *order* the IDs, like:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(GREATEST(employeeID, partnerID), ',', LEAST(employeeID, partnerID) as team, 
    SUM(bugs2010 + bugs2011 + bugs2012) as 'AMT' 
FROM Bugs_Fixed
JOIN Employees on Employees.id = Bugs_Fixed.employeeID
GROUP BY team
```

Notes - you did not tag the RDBMS that you are using:

- `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` are not supported by all RDBMS (notably, SQL Server does not support them, while MySQL, Oracle and Postgres do).
- using a table alias in the `GROUP BY` clause (here, `team`) is not allowed in SQL Server, while MySQL, Postgres and sqlite do support it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the solution your are looking for:

```
select concat(str(e.id), ', ', str(e.partner_id)) as TEAM,
    AMT = (select sum(bugs2010 + bugs2011 + bugs2012) from Bugs_Fixed
    where employee_id in (e.id, e.partner_id))
from employee e
```